# How can I do something like this - loop thru an indefinite set of numbers

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop tru a set of numbers based on the initial number. Tried, but cant see a good way to achieve this. The thing goes inside a while loop.

```
<?php

$this = 1;

//If 1 then 1,4,7
//If 2 then 3
//If 3 then 10

while ( //mySql while loop ) {
    if ( $this == 1 ) {
        call example() //thrice for 1, 4, 7
    }
}

function example($a) {
    echo $a+10;
}
?>
```

Here, based on what `$this` is, I need to call function example. So if `$this = 1`, I need to call `example` thrice - `$a` value `1, 4, 7`. If `$this = 2` I need to call it once, value `3`.

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: `$this = 1` should be `$this == 1` or you will be in an infinite loop. Also, what is the logic behind the number of times the `example` function needs to be called?

Comment: I strongly discourage you to use $this as a variable name, since it's a keyword used to reference the current instance of a class.

Comment: I only used it for this question here. Don't use it in my code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 

$this = 1;

$groups = array(
    1 => array(1,4,7),
    2 => array(3),
    3 => array(10) 
);

foreach($groups[$this] as $value)
   example($value);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an associative array like so:

```
vals = array(1 => array(1, 4, 7), 2 => array(3), etc);
```