# MySql using a while loop inside a function

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a number, how can I loop through a set of numbers based on that number, inside a MySql function?

To get a clearer picture, pls see my question where I asked how something like this could be done in php. [Question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776479/how-can-i-do-something-like-this-loop-thru-an-indefinite-set-of-numbers)

I'll be doing `select myfunction(thenumber)`. Based on that number, I got to loop.

As of now,

```
If thenumber = 1 then loop backward thru 1,4,7 only
If thenumber = 2 then loop thru 3
If thenumber = 3 then loop thru 10
```

Here's the function I've been fiddling with.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `whileloop`(`danum` VARCHAR(2050))
    RETURNS varchar(1500)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE x  INT;
DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);
SET x = danum;
SET str =  '';
#If x = 1, while = 1, 4, 7////////
WHILE x  >= 1 DO //I'm stuck here
SET  str = CONCAT(str,x,',');
SET  x = x - 1; 
END WHILE;
RETURN str;
END
```

How can I do inside a MySql function, what I did php. In php, we stored things in an array. How can we do this here?

**Edit**

*Result*

What I'm trying to get out in the end are links.

```
So if `thenumber = 1`
`<a href=foo.php?id=1> <a href=foo.php?id=4> <a href=foo.php?id=7>` //3 Links Output in a single row
If `thenumber = 2`
`<a href=foo.php?id=3>` //Same as above. Output in a single row.
If `thenumber = 10`
`<a href=foo.php?id=10>`
```

Comment: Mysql functions return only a scalar value. Therefore you can't do exactly what you've done in php. Explain more clearly what you expect to get from your function? If you pass 1 as an argument do you simply expecting a string '1, 4, 7' to be returned?

Comment: No. I want the while loop to loop through numbers 1, 4, 7. The result is a link like this (example for 1): `<a href=id=1> <a href=id=4> <a href=id=7>`

Comment: You want these links as one varchar value or you expect them to be rows?

Comment: I've edited my question. For `1` it's going be `3 links` in one single row output. For the rest, it's only a single link.

Comment: You're right. As one `varchar` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION mylink(n INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(512) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CONCAT('<a href=foo.php?id=',n,'>');

CREATE FUNCTION myfunction(n INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(512) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CASE n
    WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT(mylink(1), mylink(2), mylink(7))
    WHEN 2 THEN mylink(3)
    WHEN 3 THEN mylink(10)
END;
```

To use it

```
SELECT myfunction(n) links
FROM 
(
  SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
) a
```

Output:

```
|                                                           LINKS |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| <a href=foo.php?id=1><a href=foo.php?id=2><a href=foo.php?id=7> |
|                                           <a href=foo.php?id=3> |
|                                          <a href=foo.php?id=10> |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f976/2)** demo

Comment: Close, very close. I'm fiddling why even 3 and 10 return 3 links.

Comment: @Norman Sorry it was a typo in both functions. Updated the answer and sqlfiddle.

Comment: Works very well. I'll add all the other cases in there :)

Comment: @Norman I'm glad it helped :) If there are lots of those id combinations you might consider using a simple table for that and then use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY` to build your value.